# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: android, class, kotlin, android-manifest

hello i have merged two android apps (A,B) i.e B as library into A into it works fine but both app A and B have android:name=".MainActivityA" and android:name=".MainActivityB" i made App B launcher and it works fine but somewhere in activities MainActivityA should be called and when i make and intent call

val intent = Intent(requireContext(), Class.forName("com.test.app.MainActivityA"))
startActivity(intent)

**caused by java.lang.classcastexception android.app.application cannot be cast to** appears so how i can merge them together so that i can declare them as a single class on manifest android:name tag or what would be the best solution? thanks

Comment: Try replacing `Class.forName("com.test.app.MainActivityA")` with MainActivityA::class.java.

Comment: @AlphaOne its not working  can i combine these to classes into one is it possible??

Comment: refer this site you will found your answer bro https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574735/12543430

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivityA::class.java)
this.startActivity(intent)
```